# description list (of math) with one item not in bold

Tags: math-mode, lists, bold, description

I have a list of some math items, and I would like one not be bold, but next nonetheless. I.e. in this list I want FOOD and DOOD to be in regular text,

[image: ddoodff]

```
\documentclass{book}
 \begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[$77$]  seventy-seven
\item[FOOD$_{t}$] Food. 
\item[$\textup{DOOD}_{t}$] Dood. 
\item[$\delta$] Delta 
\end{description}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: `\textnormal`, not `\textup`

Comment: So simple. Thanks. If you add your comment as an answer I am happy to mark it as answered in full!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\textup` only acts on the shape attribute, not on the series. On the other hand, `\bfseries` is in force when typesetting the item descriptor, and `\textup` will not touch it.

What you need is `\textnormal` that resets *all* font attributes (except size).